# Mysql two tables join query take time to execute (4000 records in each table)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I write a join query for two tables, with 4000 records each, to fetch the data using php. I execute the query in mysql and it takes 32 seconds.

Here is the query

```
SELECT Distinct a.*,b.* 
FROM OrderCalculation a right join  crm_order b on a.orderid = b.orderno  
order by b.orderno desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Can anybody please improve this query and reduce the execution time

Thanks

Comment: Do you have indices on `orderid` and `orderno`?

Comment: you means index?

Comment: Yes, I meant index.

Comment: No I did not add index. I am confused to which column i have to give index

Comment: You might want to append the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE OrderCalculation;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE crm_order;` Aswell as `EXPLAIN  <your query above>;`.

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer the following index suggestion, which might improve your query performance:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON crm_order (orderno, col1, col2, ...);
```

I would only suggest this if you have no more than say 4-5 other columns in the `crm_order` table to cover.  If you have more than that, it might make sense to not use this index.

If it helps, the index is working by letting MySQL rapidly lookup each `orderno` value from the `OrderCalculation` table.  This would also assume that MySQL would do a full table scan of the `OrderCalculation` table.  You might want to first run `EXPLAIN` on your current query to see where you stand.

Comment: MySQL 8 optimizer would do a reverse index scan on `order by b.orderno desc` and access that table first.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yeah...I figured that might also happen.

Answer (score 0):

As your join is using `orderid` and `orderno` columns of `OrderCalculation` and `crm_order` tables respectively, you can add index on these two columns and measure the performance.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) MySQL documentation on how to create index.

Comment: Not sure if an index only on `orderno` would even be used by both tables, as it couldn't cover the other columns included by `SELECT *` (unless of course a table only has an `orderno` column).

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, we would normally write that query this way:

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant 
  FROM crm_order a 
  LEFT
  JOIN OrderCalculation b
    ON b.orderid = a.orderno  
 ORDER  
    BY b.orderno DESC
 LIMIT 0,20
```